# migrating osgi from bndlib to osgi r6 declrative services

Tags: osgi, osgi-bundle, apache-felix, bnd, bndtools

We migrated our OSGi application from biz.aQute.bnd to osgi.org(r6 declarative services) and currently running through some issues. Even though the application is compiling with no errors, it is not coming up after running. There might be some possible issues, such as dependency conflicts caused by third-party libraries, classpath issues, etc. Since it is not throwing any compile-time/runtime errors, it is difficult to figure out where it went wrong. Can someone provide any helpful leads regarding how to tackle this situation?

We tried compiling the application in debug mode to see if the application is throwing any errors and also trying to figure out whether there are any dependency conflicts, for example, trying to find out if there are any dependencies that are not compatible with OSGi r6. since it is not throwing any errors, it is difficult to know what is going wrong.

Comment: Do you have a logfile with stack traces? Most likely it is a dependency issue but without a stacktrace hard to answer.